# update select tag from database

Tags: php, mysql

select.php

```
<?php
echo '<form method="post"><table>
         <tr><td>Region<select name="region">
                    <option value="0">Choose</option>
                    <option value="1">True</option>
                    <option value="2">False</option>
         </td></tr>
         <tr><td><input type="submit" value="submit"></td></tr>
      </table></form>';
?>
```

edit.php

```
<?php
echo '<table>
         <tr><td>Region <select id="selector">';
      $region = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM region');
        echo '<option selected="selected">Choose</option>';
        foreach($region as $pr)
        {
              $region = $pr->region;
          echo '<option value='.$region.'>'.$region.'</option>';          
            }
        echo '</select>';
         </td></tr>
      </table>';
?>
```

Iam submitting the region to database successfully by values 0,1,2 and when in edit mode I need to get the selected one as first.

Comment: echo '</select>';
         </td></tr>
      </table>';  should be echo '</select>
         </td></tr>
      </table>';  into edit.php page

Answer (score 0):

into edit.php page get the value and store it into variable,like this

if you use `GET` method

```
$value=$_GET['selected_id'];
```

or if you use `POST` method

```
$value=$_POST['selected_id'];
```

then use below code to get selected value

```
<option value="<?php echo $region; ?>" <?php if($value==$region){ echo "selected";} ?> ><?php echo $regio; ?></option>
```

may be if is useful for you.

Answer (score 0):

Modify as in edit.php

```
<select name="selector">
```

Correct your edit.php at last echo as

```
 echo '</select></td></tr>';
```

Then evaluate the submitted form

```
$selected_option = $_POST['selector'];
```

Comment: it shows only True, but I need all but with top priority with the value stored in database

Comment: @karthik what do you want to achieve is not clear. Paste some data from tables / table structure. What priority?